# Error 403 al usar una api

Tags: python, api, scraping, error-403

estoy intento usar la api `https://data.similarweb.com/api/v1/data?domain=` que me debería de devolver un json con datos de visitas y ranking de la web que acompaña al parámetro `domain`, pero por una razón que no logro a entender me el `.status_code` me devuelve un error 403.

Espero que me puedan echar una mano.
Gracias de antemano

```
from requests import get

web = 'www.wikipedia.com'
endpoint = web.replace("www.", "")
url = 'https://data.similarweb.com/api/v1/data?domain=' + endpoint
resp = get(url)

if resp.status_code == 200:
    resp.json()
else:
    resp.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: Qué valor tiene `url` al concatenar `endpoint`? Si `url` es valor estático no sería mejor enviar la `url` sin concatenar `endpoint`?

Comment: te devuelve ese status, y el mensaje que dice

Comment: @Bicho la cuestión de concatenar es porque ese trozo de código viene de un programa que toma una lista de webs que proceden de otro documento. Solo se ha puesto una para el ejemplo, pero tienes razón que no aporta mucho a la explicación del problema.

Comment: Intenta con `print(requests.get("https://data.similarweb.com/api/v1/data?domain=www.wikipedia.com", headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla"}))`

Comment: SI! ha funcionado. Te importaría ilustrarnos y arrojar luz sobre este tema. No me puedo creer que devuelva un 200.

Answer (score 1):

La `url` a la cual le estas haciendo el `request` las esta bloqueando. Esto lo se ya que en el codigo, en vez de obtener el `.json()` intento obtener el codigo html del request y entre todo lo que obtengo destaco esto:

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content">

            <div id="px-captcha">
            </div>
            <p>
                Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the
                website.
            </p>
            <p>
                This may happen as a result of the following:
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Javascript is disabled or blocked by an extension (ad blockers for example)
                </li>
                <li>
                    Your browser does not support cookies
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p>
                Please make sure that Javascript and cookies are enabled on your browser and that you are not blocking
                them from loading.
            </p>
            <p>
                Reference ID: #a083c370-71f8-11eb-995a-878a835445e5
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Tambien lo he intentado añadiendo `User Agents` pero tampoco funciona. El response te dice los posibles motivos:

`Javascript is disabled or blocked by an extension (ad blockers for example)`

`Your browser does not support cookies`

---

Ahora mismo no se como solucionarlo pero a poder ser cambia de API